# In Wordpress, how do I get rid of the mobile stylesheet?

Tags: wordpress

I bought a Wordpress template from Elegant Themes, the CSS is here: http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/style.css.

And the demo for the theme is (http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Nimble).

The web layout automatically resizes with different screen sizes on cellphones/ipads/etc. How do you turn off this feature?

It shifts the images on different mobile devices. I want the website to use the main screen stylesheet, and how it appears on the computer screen.

What line of code do I have to erase, so that the website will appear the same way on each device? The url for the site is here: http://healthevolution.ca/

Answer (score 2):

open header.php which is located in wp-contnet/themes/your-theme/header.php in your theme and remove this line   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`
and save it.....

Comment: find above and remove it

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off responsive layouts from the epanel.

From http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-changesbug-fixes/deepfocus-now-fully-responsive:

> If for whatever reason you do not want your theme to be responsive,
>   you can always turn off responsive design from within ePanel.